# Wordpress SQL Query to combine column data for all rows

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress plugin which allows users to save favorite posts. In my Wordpress MySQL database, the table looks like the following:

```
id     | user_id | post_id  
-------+---------+------------
1      | 1       | 3,4,5,6,7,8  
2      | 2       | 5,7,8,10
3      | 5       | 3,6,8,10
```

I'm looking to take all the `post_id` numbers, and combine them into a variable so that I can `foreach` them to find how many matches there are to the current post I'm reading.

For example, if I'm reading post ID 10, I want to be able to see that there are 2 people who have saved it as favorites.

I've tried `$data = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_id FROM $table_name");` and `var_dump($data);` but that only returns **my** favorite posts, not **ALL** the favorite posts.

Comment: Your comment isn't very constructive. No I did not design it.

Comment: Normalizing it is a constructive comment because that's what the solution to your problem is.

Comment: Perhaps you could be helpful and explain how to normalize it? Maybe even answer the question? Like I said, telling me my table is "built wrong" is not constructive.

Comment: To provide a counterpoint: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html -- "Obviously it should be normalized!" is a naive battlecry.  When you are working with other people's business logic sometimes you need to use what you have, not rewrite their work to get your job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I did play devils advocate in the comments regarding normalization, this table layout does seem pretty braindead.  However, if you are unable to normalize the database tables and have to work with what you have, you can technically do what you ask with a rather hacky sql statement:

```
SELECT count(user_id) as TotalWishes
FROM table_name
WHERE (
 (post_id LIKE 'n,%') OR
 (post_id LIKE '%,n,%') OR
 (post_id LIKE '%,n')
 )
```

where n in this example is the number of your post.

I felt dirty even writing that, but in the strictest interpretation of your question, this query should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the help. As dirty as it is, it works great with the code/structure I was handed.